# intercept all stdout, stderr and return code of all commands call in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have a brunch of bash scripts. I need to capture the stdout, stderr and return code of individual command call separately inside each bash script.

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
wget https://xyz/1.tar.gz
wget https://abc/2.tar.gz
```

I want to get the stdout, stderr and error code of the lines `wget https://xyz/1.tar.gz` and `wget https://abc/2.tar.gz` separately and analyse the outputs.

I have too many script that I can't edit them one by one.
Is there any runner or tool that I can do simple call to the high level script like:

```
run_and_capture_and_analyse.sh myscript.sh
```

I've came across the `DEBUG` trap approach. But the problem is that I still need to edit each script add the trap. Also, there is no way to really capture the outputs.

Thank you

EDITED:
In an ideal situation, I want the outputs (stdout, stderr, return code) to be logged in different file/pipe. I only care external commands, so native controls like `echo` are not required. Pipe outputs should be captured just like other outputs.

Comment: Without modifying the scripts you'll need something that can parse them. A bash debugger might be able to do that.

Comment: Will the debug output of `set -x` not work? Do you need to capture `stdout` and `stderr` in the same output file?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : If I understand the OP correctly, he wants to capture the output of different commands into different files.

Comment: Is it only `wget` commands you want to capture, or **all** commands (including, i.e., `echo`)? What happens with commands which are part of a pipe, i.e. something like `foo|bar`? Do you want to have the output of `foo` also stored somewhere?

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify some of the question above. thank you.

Comment: In general, I would use sysdig or ebpftrace for this instead of trying to modify your script at all (or, at a much larger performance penalty, `strace -o out.trace -f`). As a bonus, once you know how to use them, they'll work for analyzing behavior of software written in any other language as well. (Also, sysdig is very much amenable to programmatic use -- you can write "chisels" that analyze its traces in Lua, or spit out filtered subsets in JSON to parse with whatever tools you personally prefer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thx for your answer. after digging in some of the documentation, the tools look really good. but one thing I can't find is the error code returned by the executables. can you shed some light on it?